# Tunneling SQL queries through central server

Tags: sql-server

The company I work for has multiple branch offices over the globe, but each is only connected through VPN/EVPL to our main office.

```
Office A ------- Main Office ------ Office B
```

What is the best way to query data from an MSSQL DB that is located in Office A from Office B?

My first approach was writing stored procedures on the main office SQL, like "QueryDataB" or "QueryDataA", but this is very tedious and I bet there is a better way, like tunneling a connection through or something like this?

Comment: Talk with your network admin and ask if they can help.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, maybe you can clarify, are there multiple SQL Servers?...are you trying to query data from all / multiple servers at one time or just a single specific server each time?

Comment: @J.D. every office has a SQL server. It's our ERP backend. I'm only querying data from one specific server for one specific dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such "tunneling" feature built-in to SQL server.

The closest you can come is to setup [Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) on each branch office's SQL Server to point to the central SQL Server. You will probably shy away from this after you evaluated it, due to performance, management overhead etc.

If you still want to stick with Linked Servers, then you might want to define [Synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) on each branch server for each relevant table pointing to the table on the central server. I.e., it will look like, from a naming perspective, that the table is local.

Again, after you have evaluated above, you will likely go for something more "performant" and with less management overhead: I.e., talk to your network admin,  as suggested by vonPryz.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. Especially with the synonyms!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend build a data warehouse server in your main office or in the cloud which will contain detailed or aggregated (depending on needs) data from all offices.
Such solution will allow you for easy comparison of data between the offices and minimize amount of data that needs to be transferred over VPNs. Also it will speed up all reports than needs data from more than one office.

Comment: This is not possible due to customer guidelines, especially from automotive customers. They have very strict guidelines. We always need only these tiny bits of data, most of the time only for single orders.